# When I hit Cloud server Springboot Rest url, response is (type=Unauthorized, status=401)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have Angualr8 frontend and Springboot backend code, when I am trying to hit the local URL with parm values it works fine but when I am trying to hit the same in prod it gives the below error am not sure is this for the token missing issue.

**working URL: http://localhost:8080/apiservice/forgotPasswordEmail?userId=userid**

PROD cloud not working URL:  **http://prod-host/apiservice/forgotPasswordEmail?userId=userid**

can you please help me in this case?

**CONTROLLER:**

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {""}) //having my structure
@RequestMapping(value = "/apiservice")
public class LoeRedirectController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPasswordEmail", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String redirectForgotPassword(@RequestParam  String userId) {
        String url="http://localhost:8080/index.html";  //for prod it will prod url
         if(null !=url) {
            // url=url+"?userId="+userId; 
         }
        return "redirect:"+url;
    }
```

**SS:**

[image]

web config file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/**");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please share your security configuration. A 401 status points to something being wrong with the credentials you are providing. Check that you are making the request with a user that exists in production.

Comment: please find security config in above

Comment: The security configuration is disabling security for all endpoint. If you aren't using Spring Security it is best to simply remove the security dependency

Comment: Thanks  @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, I removed and worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I remove security in pom.xml its worked